# how to obfuscate my WCF Proxy classes dll using Dotfuscator Community Edition

Tags: dotfuscator

I am using Dotfuscator and Analytics Community Edition [Version-5.5.45].
I want to obfuscate my dll , all the classes inside that dll are obfuscated,but wcf proxy classes are not obfuscated in Dotfuscator Community Edition?
**It is possible to obfuscate the wcf proxy classes in dotfucator community edition?
When i try to obfuscate normally, i am getting the following in Smart Obfuscation page,
Property: mypropertyname::ShouldSerializePrompt was excluded from metadata stripping by Net30Rule for the following reasons: mypropertynameis decorated with System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute.
Method: mymethodname::void .ctor(string, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress) was excluded from renaming by Net30Rule for the following reasons: mymethodname was excluded from renaming.
User Type: usertypname was excluded from renaming by Net30Rule for the following reasons: usertypename was excluded from renaming.**

Can i get any ideas?

Comment: Did you not like my edit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obfuscate WCF Proxy Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697455/obfuscate-wcf-proxy-classes)

Comment: i read that post in that they mentioned for  Dotfuscator Pro Edition, i want to conform whether it is applicable to Dotfuscator Community Edition,because i am using Dotfuscator community Edition.I am new to dotfusctor , i am not much aware of it.  Hope it is applicable to Dotfuscator community Edition.. Am i right???

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any point of obfuscating the proxies. Web methods are by design public. You want people to use it, so why obfuscate the names? Imaging the whole Internet was obfuscated, so instead of `www.google.com` you had to type `kj5anld033ik1lkqef`. Plus once google release an update to their interface you would need to type something else, like `jjfoq0394jhq1f`. Not fun.

There are other ways to protect your server code (like authentication, authorisation, encryption, use of data transfer objects etc). Proxy code is a dummy pointer to the servers, so no need to obfuscate. This is security by obscurity (meaning you only fooling yourself and not protecting).